# How to move only selected files from one folder to another in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-explorer

I have 1000 images file in one folder. Based on their clarity, I will note down image name and need to move to another folder.

But selecting images one by one using the mouse, based on my selected list, is a tedious process.

Is there any command line code or shortcut to move only the selected images from one to another folder?

Comment: Ctrl + A, selects all. Ctrl + X, cuts. Ctrl + V, paste.

Comment: @jason i need command line code to move selected multiple files at same time ,other than above normal cut copy paste

Comment: Go back to dos ... copy command

Comment: Use a decent file manager.

Answer (score 1):

If you have all the files in a .csv (including their extensions), a simple PowerShell script can do the job:

```
$Files = Get-Content F:\Temp\Book1.csv
$Source = "F:\Temp\Test"
$Destination = "F:\Temp\Destination"

foreach ($SourceFile in $Files) {
Move-Item "$Source\$SourceFile" -Destination $Destination
}
```

This will read the exact files names from F:\Temp\Book1.csv, look for them in F:\Temp\Test, and move them to F:\Temp\Destination if they exist.

This will take editing to work in your situation, but hopefully it is enough to get you started.